# How to open PDF file on ng-click instead of downloading in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am able to download the file when user clicked on this link `"Click to get your file"`. But now I need to open the PDF file (like modal window) and restrict the user from downloading the file.

**My Controller**

```
var resumeJson = {
        "json":{
            "request":{
                "candidateid":$rootScope.globals.currentUser.userId,
                "type":2
             }
          }
       };


$scope.getResume = function() {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(resumeJson));
      $scope.resume = UserService.getFile(resumeJson);
      console.log($scope.resume);    
 }
```

**My Html**

```
<div class="grid_3" ng-show="resumeflag==true || uploaded==true" ng-hide="resumeflag==false || uploaded==false">
   <a  ng-click="getResume()" href="{{resume}}">
       <img ng-src="images/resume.png" style="height:4em; width:4em;" ng-click="getResume()" href="{{resume}}">Click to get Your Resume</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you want for web or mobile?

Comment: for web i need.

Answer (score 0):

What about an iframe?

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getResume = function() {
    UserService.getFile(resumeJson)
        .then(function(response) {
            var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf', charset:'utf-8'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.resume = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="resume" src="{{resume}}" onload="setSize()"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSize() {
        document.getElementById('resume').style.height = '100%';
        document.getElementById('resume').style.width = '100%'; 
    }
</script>
```